# Алгоритм решения к задаче

Tags: алгоритм

В общем, нужен алгоритм к [задаче](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view3.php?id=656&chapterid=2962#1), которая написана внизу.

Вот моя идея : идея за `O(N^2)`, база динамики `dp[0][0] = 1`, и потом просто бежим по клеткам, и в каждую клетку записываем сумму значений клеток, из которых мы можем попасть в эту клетку, т.е `dp[i][j] = dp[i - 2][j - 1] + dp[i - 2][j + 1]`...

И это не работает. Я даже знаю почему, но не знаю, как это исправить.

> Дана прямоугольная доска N × M (N строк и M столбцов). В левом верхнем углу находится шахматный конь, которого необходимо переместить в правый нижний угол доски. При этом конь может ходить только : на 2 клетки вправо и на одну либо вверх, либо вниз, или на 2 клетки вниз и на одну либо вправо, либо влево.
>
> Необходимо определить, сколько существует различных маршрутов, ведущих из левого верхнего в правый нижний угол.
>
> Формат входного файла
> В первой строке входного файла находятся два натуральных числа N и M (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 15).
>
> Формат выходного файла
> В выходной файл выведите единственное число количество способов добраться конём до правого нижнего угла доски.
>
> `Вх. данные                    Выход
> 15 14                        7884330`

Comment: > И это не работает. Я даже знаю почему, но не знаю, как это исправить.
Так почему же?

Comment: потому что, когда мы пререходим например на 2 строку, то значение первой строки может измениться, за счет того, что можно ходить враво и вверх! т.е. можно вернуться в исходное положение!

Comment: может не по строкам надо ходить, а двигая побочную диагональ где i+j=const

Comment: пропускайте клетки которые вы уже обработали, - так вы избавитесь от рекурсий

Comment: @jmu какие рекурсии тут? дело @Yuri Ivanov говорит

Comment: > @jmu какие рекурсии тут?

вы утверждаете что если двигатся подобным образом то вы никогда не попадете в одну и ту же точку сетки?

касательно алгоритма: если я правильно понял он будет бежать по всем клеткам, хотя теоретически должны быть такие в которые он не сможет попасть

Comment: @jmu просто автор явно указал решение O(n^2) которое для каждой клетки считает лишь один раз, просто не с совсем верным порядком просчета

Comment: вот [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/P8wAy/) на JavaScript'е =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, я решил эту задачу, всем спасибо! Особенно [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) за интересное решение! Решил "Ленивой динамикой". Ниже код на С++:

```
#define FOR(a, k, b) for(int a = k; a < b; a++)

void initial()
{
    FOR(i, 0, n)
        FOR(j, 0, m)
            dp[i][j] = -1;
    dp[0][0] = 1;
}

bool good(int i, int j)
{
    return (i >= 0) && (j >= 0) && (i < n) && (j < m);
}

int solve(int i, int j)
{
    if (good(i, j))
    {
        if (dp[i][j] == -1)     
            dp[i][j] = solve(i - 2, j - 1) + solve(i - 2, j + 1) + solve(i - 1, j - 2) + solve(i + 1, j - 2);
    } else 
        return 0;
    return dp[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    initial();
    printf("%d", solve(n - 1, m - 1));    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересный у вас макрос.

Comment: Макросы - штука прикольная конечно. Даже не знаю, хорошо или плохо что они не вписываются в концепцию java...