# Оптимизация алгоритмической задачи про ход коня

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

Дана прямоугольная доска размером NхM. В левом верхнем углу находится шахматный конь, которого необходимо переместить в правый нижний угол доски. В данной задаче конь может перемещаться на две клетки вниз и одну клетку вправо или на одну клетку вниз и две клетки вправо.

Необходимо определить, сколько существует различных маршрутов, ведущих из левого верхнего в правый нижний угол.

N и M находятся в пределах от 1 до 50. Ограничение по времени работы - 1000 мс, по памяти - 64 мб.

Пример 1:
Вход: N=1 M=1
Выход: 0

Пример 2:
Вход: N=3 M=2
Выход: 1

Пример 3:
Вход: N=31 M=34
Выход: 293930

Я написал следующее решение:

```
public class Main {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50; // input N
        int m = 50; // input M
        walk(0, 0, n-1, m-1);
        System.out.println(counter); // Output result
    }

    private static void walk(int i, int j, int n, int m) {
        if (i < n && j < m) {
            walk(i + 2, j + 1, n, m);
            walk(i + 1, j + 2, n, m);
        } else if (i == n && j == m) {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Однако с этим решением есть проблема с тем, что при больших значениях входных параметров время работы алгоритма не укладывается в 1000мс (пример, N=50, M=50). Какие есть варианты оптимизации?

Я попробовал переделать на стек, но это только ухудшило время работы. Не знаю стоит ли тут рассматривать добавление многопоточной реализации, так как кажется, что есть менее брутальный вариант оптимизации.

Comment: По-моему, дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/139167/195342, нет?

Comment: См. https://site.ada.edu.az/~medv/acm/Docs%20e-olimp/Volume%2041/4021.htm

Comment: Задача очень похожа, но есть нюанс в том, что в данной задаче конь может ходит только 1 раз вниз и 2 вправо, либо 2 вниз и 1 вправо. Но в какую сторону смотреть понятно, попробую разобраться, спасибо.
P.S. по второй ссылке пример на java не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного разобравшись в решении, которое привел @Harry и подправив код, получился следующий рабочий вариант:

```
public class Main {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50; // input N
        int m = 50; // input M
        int dp[][] = new int[n+1][m+1];
        dp[1][1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= m; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-2] + dp[i-2][j-1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(dp[n][m])); // Output result
    }
}
```